# WebView: Loading a local website with directories, css's, htmls, etc stored in a folder inside assets

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-assets

It is possible in Android to load a complex website stored in a folder inside assets android folder... with html, javascript, folders with css files, images etc...? Can't find any info about this in google.

Which is the best approach to achieve this?

Which limitations will have this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can and you can download awd IDE to do it. It creates a folder and you allows you to creates html/js/css/php files